# Matplotlib subplot How to adjust time series x-axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to combine 2 plots in the same figure (2 lines ) . when I show it separately , there is no problem with x-axes (time series ) but when I put them together following the code below , the x-axes 
i don't now where is the mistake :
code :

```
fig, (ax2, ax1) = plt.subplots(2)
fig.suptitle('covid-19 Madagasikara')
# first axe

# pour les axes 
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(30,25)},palette=['#F70A0A','#2A930C','#930C85'], font_scale=1.7)
ax1 = sns.barplot(x=df_final_seaborn.index,y='Isan\'ny olona',data=df_final_seaborn,hue='Covid-19 Madagascar' , ax = ax1)
sns.set_style("darkgrid" , {"ytick.major.size": 10 , "ytick.minor.size": 2 , 'grid.linestyle': '--'})
# X-axis for first figure 
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(df_sea.index.to_series().dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
for patch in ax1.patches:
    x , width , height = patch.get_x(),patch.get_width(),patch.get_height()
    color = patch.get_facecolor()
    #ignore . and nan values 
    if height is None or height ==0:continue

    ax1.text(x+width/2,height+0.1,height.astype(int),ha='center',color=color)

 # ------------------------------second figure--------------------------

# pour les axes 
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(30,25)},palette=['#0524C1','#F70A0A'], font_scale=1.7)
ax2 = sns.barplot(x=df_final_seaborn_with_test.index,y='Isan\'ny olona',data=df_final_seaborn_with_test,hue='Covid-19 Madagascar' , ax=ax2)
sns.set_style("darkgrid" , {"ytick.major.size": 10 , "ytick.minor.size": 2 , 'grid.linestyle': '--'})
# X-axis for second figure 
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(df_test.index.to_series().dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))

for patch in ax2.patches:
    x , width , height = patch.get_x(),patch.get_width(),patch.get_height()
    color = patch.get_facecolor()
    #ignore . and nan values 
    if height is None or height ==0:continue

    ax2.text(x+width/2,height+0.1,height.astype(int),ha='center',color=color)


plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Daty', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Isan\'ny olona', fontsize = 20)
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#999999', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2 , axis='y')

plt.show()
```

the result

[image]

Solution  : I added the code below by putting the previous code in comment :

```
# X-axis 
for ax in (ax1 ,ax2):
    ax.tick_params(axis='x',labelrotation=90)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(df_sea.index.to_series().dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `plt.xticks()` operates on the current axis.

You can iterate over the axes though:

```
for ax in (ax1,ax2): 
    ax.tick_params(axis='x',labelrotation=90)
```